# Php mobile/tablet/desktop detect?

Tags: php, device-detection

How to detect with php, if the user use a desktop, mobile or a tablet?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you checkout following code: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Comment: This is really the best Script I came across. FYI, they moved to GitHub: https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect

Answer (score 1):

You could also try this one

http://detectmobilebrowsers.mobi/